# Trouble Managing User Sessions in Mobile App - Suggestions?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a mobile app using React Native and am facing an issue with managing user sessions... I am utilizing Redux for state management and have integrated Redux Persist to save the authentication state to local storage.

However, despite the state seemingly being saved correctly, the user is logged out every time the app is closed and reopened...

I have followed the Redux Persist documentation closely and ensured that my authentication reducer is set up correctly. I've also tried debugging by logging the state to the console, and it appears that the state is being rehydrated correctly on app launch, but the user is still logged out...

I am wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions on what might be going wrong? I am not sure if there's something I might be overlooking in the Redux or Redux Persist setup that could be causing this issue...

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

I tried to follow a tutorial to set up Redux  -and Redux Persist in my app to keep the user logged in even after they close the app.

I followed the steps carefully  and checked my code multiple times to make sure it matches the tutorial...

I also added some console.log statements to see if the user's login info is being saved and it seems like it is. Bt when I close and reopen the app, the user is logged out and has to log in again, which isn't supposed to happen...

I was expecting that the user would stay logged in between app uses because that's what Redux Persist is supposed to do, right? I looked for answers online and tried some suggestions, but nothing worked.

I'm not sure what to try next and I'm hoping someone here can help me figure out what I might be doing wrong...

Comment: Provide an minimal code example. Which tutorial do you follow?